# Should I close the connections?

Tags: magento2, database

Just a question, is it a good practice to close connections after opening?
I open connections as follows:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
```

Magento 2

Comment: Yes if there is no other query related task, and don’t use object manager in code

Comment: and how do i do that? 
I tried $resource->closeConnection();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can close the connection by below example.

```
$this->_resource->closeConnection();
```

Below is the full details for a custom connection without using the object manager.

```
    protected $_resource;
    public function __construct(      
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    )
    {
        $this->_resource = $resource;      
    }

    
    public function execute()
    {
        $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
        $data = $connection->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM tabel_name');
        $this->_resource->closeConnection();      
    }
```

For more details, you can check this file

```
vendor/magento/framework/App/ResourceConnection.php
```

Comment: Thank you for that!