# Magento 2 spawns many consumers per queue over time

Tags: message-queue, queue, consumers

I'm using many queues and configure Magento to use separate consumers for every queue. It works well. But every few days it probably misses all consumer locks and spawns new processes for all queues. After a couple of weeks I see the following process list:

```
Load average: 1.60 1.51 1.23 2/275 3469
  PID  PPID USER     STAT   VSZ %VSZ CPU %CPU COMMAND
  443    14 php      S     338m   2%   2   0% php-fpm: pool www
  664    14 php      S     338m   2%   1   0% php-fpm: pool www
 3089    14 php      S     338m   2%   1   0% php-fpm: pool www
   14     1 root     S     335m   2%   3   0% php-fpm: master process (/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf)
10474     1 php      S     205m   1%   2   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start sync.m2.redacted1 --single-thread --max-messages=10000
23912     1 php      S     205m   1%   1   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start sync.m2.redacted1 --single-thread --max-messages=10000
31940     1 php      S     205m   1%   2   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start sync.m2.redacted1 --single-thread --max-messages=10000
28414     1 php      S     205m   1%   0   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start sync.m2.redacted1 --single-thread --max-messages=10000
 2591     1 php      S     205m   1%   2   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start sync.m2.redacted2 --single-thread --max-messages=10000
10044     1 php      S     205m   1%   2   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start sync.m2.redacted2 --single-thread --max-messages=10000
23455     1 php      S     205m   1%   2   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start sync.m2.redacted2 --single-thread --max-messages=10000
28422     1 php      S     205m   1%   3   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start sync.m2.redacted2 --single-thread --max-messages=10000
31948     1 php      S     203m   1%   0   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start sync.m2.redacted2 --single-thread --max-messages=10000
12464     1 php      S     201m   1%   3   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start sync.m2.redacted3 --single-threa
25883     1 php      S     201m   1%   1   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start sync.m2.redacted3 --single-threa
28430     1 php      S     201m   1%   3   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start sync.m2.redacted3 --single-threa
31956     1 php      S     201m   1%   3   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start sync.m2.redacted3 --single-threa
 2577     1 php      S     199m   1%   1   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start async.m2.redacted4 --single-thread --max-messages=10
15911     1 php      S     199m   1%   3   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start async.m2.redacted4 --single-thread --max-messages=10
29285     1 php      S     199m   1%   3   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start async.m2.redacted4 --single-thread --max-messages=10
10077     1 php      S     199m   1%   3   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start async.m2.redacted4 --single-thread --max-messages=10
24946     1 php      S     199m   1%   2   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start async.m2.redacted4 --single-thread --max-messages=10
28406     1 php      S     199m   1%   2   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start async.m2.redacted4 --single-thread --max-messages=10
31932     1 php      S     199m   1%   0   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start async.m2.redacted4 --single-thread --max-messages=10
14457     1 php      S     199m   1%   3   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start sync.m2.redacted5 --single-thread --max-messages=10000
27649     1 php      S     199m   1%   1   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start sync.m2.redacted5 --single-thread --max-messages=10000
 2595     1 php      S     199m   1%   3   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start sync.m2.redacted5 --single-thread --max-messages=10000
29748     1 php      S     199m   1%   2   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start sync.m2.redacted5 --single-thread --max-messages=10000
10564     1 php      S     199m   1%   1   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start sync.m2.redacted5 --single-thread --max-messages=10000
28428     1 php      S     199m   1%   2   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start sync.m2.redacted5 --single-thread --max-messages=10000
31954     1 php      S     199m   1%   2   0% /usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento queue:consumers:start sync.m2.redacted5 --single-thread --max-messages=10000
```

(command lines truncated because some queue names are long and I've redacted real queue names)

You may see that every queue has many consumers. When the server is just started up, I see only one consumer per queue.

How to fix this?

Comment: Please post TEXT of your code responsible for Connect, Process, Close.  With so many STAT of S (Sleeping), it appears the Close is being missed when activity for a task is completed.  Result is many orphaned processes not releasing resources in a timely manner and depending on WAIT_TIMEOUT to end the process - a mistake for a healthy/stable system.

Comment: The code responsible for managing processes is the Magento core. What exactly you expect to see?

Comment: Connect, Process and no CLOSE.  Here is a URL to study for an example.  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/315987/should-i-close-the-connections  
scroll down thru the article to see the close.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want me to close if I'm using the core Magento code to manage consumers.

Comment: Another way of verifying the Magento code is missing the CLOSE is with this query.  
    SELECT 'SLEEPING Ram use', 
COUNT(*),SUM(time),SUM(memory_used),SUM(max_memory_used) 
FROM information_schema.processlist 
WHERE 
command="Sleep";     Please post TEXT results of this query and we will go from there on a plan of action.

Comment: @WilsonHauck the memory fields do not exist. I deleted them and this is what I got: `SLEEPING Ram use 18 297785`

Comment: Average of 16K per process not released.  Please post entire TEXT results of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; we may see some processess that  have been sleeping for an extended number of seconds and will go away when WAIT_TIMEOUT period expires, may or may not release the memory currently occupied.

Comment: I just found that despite all consumers starting with the `--single-thread` argument, after some time I can run another process with the `--single-thread` argument for the same consumer name. This should not happen because the `\Magento\Framework\Lock\LockManagerInterface::lock()` method should not allow this. That means the locks are released after some time themselves.

Comment: Another find - I stopped the cron daemon on an instance and after 12 hours the MySQL process list is nearly empty while I can see a lot of consumer processes running.

Comment: Please check with your Magento support team when you get this deep into who, what, when locks become free.  When we can not view a SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;  complete report, we are only guessing related to your workload.

Comment: It seems like the processes are not exiting by some other reason not related to DB locks.

Comment: Please consider posting complete results of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; Thanks